# Rails polymorphic has_many through association - form broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5.1 app I am trying to create a tagging system from scratch.

I want `Tags` to be a polymorphic `has_many :through` association so that I can tag multiple models.

Currently I'm able to create a `Tag` (and the associated `Tagging`) in the console by doing: `Note.last.tags.create(name: "example")` which generates the correct SQL:

```
Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "notes".* FROM "notes" ORDER BY "notes"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "example"], ["created_at", "2017-10-21 14:41:43.961516"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-21 14:41:43.961516"]]
Note Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("created_at", "updated_at", "tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2017-10-21 14:41:43.978286"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-21 14:41:43.978286"], ["tag_id", 9], ["taggable_id", 4], ["taggable_type", "Note"]]
```

But when trying to create a `Tag` and its associations through my form it doesn't work. I can create the `Tag` but no `Tagging`.

**controllers/notes/tags_controller.rb**

```
class Notes::TagsController < TagsController
  before_action :set_taggable

  private

  def set_taggable
    @taggable = Note.find(params[:note_id])
  end
end
```

**controllers/tags_controller.rb**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @tag = @taggable.tags.new(tag_params)
    @tag.user_id = current_user.id

    if @tag.save
      redirect_to @taggable, success: "New tag created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def tag_params
    params.require(:tag).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
resources :notes, except: [:index] do
  resources :tags, module: :notes
end
...
```

.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :taggables, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**notes/show.html.erb**

```
<p><%= @note.body %></p>
<%= render partial: 'tags/tags', locals: { taggable: @note } %>
<%= render partial: 'tags/form', locals: { taggable: @note }  %>
```

**tags/form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [taggable, Tag.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be that the Tagging is not getting saved due to the :tag association being required by default.

Try:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag, required: false
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: With this change I still have the same behaviour I'm afraid

Comment: @BillyBib I think this edit could be the solution. If it doesn't work try recreating the issue on the console and checking the errors on the tag you are trying to create. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Gave that a go and got `Unknown key: :required`. Had a go at recreating in the console, but it works perfectly when I do `Note.last.tags.create(name: "pablo")`

Comment: That's weird, the `required` option should be recognized. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentially flawed in that it will create duplicates of each tag instead of creating a join record. It also adds unessicary complication in that you have to create nested controllers for each taggable resource.

The fact that this does not fail a uniqueness validation for `tags.name` shows a shortcoming in your application - you should have a unique index in the DB and a validation in the model to avoid duplicates.

This would be a perfectly fine approach for something like comments where each created record should be unique but is not for this case where you're linking to an indirect association.

To assign existing tags to a record you can use a select or checkboxes to pass an array of ids:

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <%= f.collection_checkboxes(:tags_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

To create new tags you can use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or use ajax to send a POST request to `/tags` and update the view so that the tag ends up in the list of checkboxes.